# For loop that doesn't get entered

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I got this for loop in a function, but it never gets entered,

```
   for (Window *window in _app.windows) {
                        NSLog(@"test.");

    }
```

I'm a beginner so where do I start to debug this and see where it goes wrong?

**EDIT**
This is in another class

(its in a function (loadApp) that I call in my ViewController, like this:     self.app = [MyClass loadApp]; , the above code is also in my ViewController.

```
        Window *window = [[Window alloc] initWithName:title subtitle:subtitle number:number ident:ident type:type chapternumber:chapternumber icon:icon text:text img:img question:question answerFormat:answerFormat answerLength:answerLength tip1:tip1 tip2:tip2 tip3:tip3 tip1Answer:tip1Answer tip2Answer:tip2Answer tip3Answer:tip3Answer];

    [app.windows addObject:window];

}

return app;
```

Comment: You're attempting to perform fast enumeration on an array. If your expression `_app.windows` is nil, or is empty, you'll never enter the loop.

Comment: I did a simple if(_app == nil) and it isn't nil

Comment: Then `windows` must be empty, i.e., contain no elements.

Comment: 1- It's UIWindow, not Window    2 - Even if _app.windows might not be nil, you'd still get no result if it's an empty array   will post code for your debugging now

Comment: I can't test if window is nil, since I can only access that variable in the for loop and the for loop doesn't get entered

Comment: Window is my own class that I made

Comment: NSLog _app and _app.windows.

Comment: With regard to your edit: Is it `_app`, or is it `app`? You're adding a `Window` object to `app.windows`, but you're attempting to enumerate `_app.windows`. That implies that `_app.windows` never has anything put into it, and so it is empty, and so you never enter that loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
if(!_app)  {
  NSLog(@"app is nil");
}
else if(!_app.windows) {
  NSLog(@"windows is nil");
}
else  {
  NSLog(@"there are %d windows", [_app.windows count]);
}
```

I suspect you'll see there are 0 windows

Comment: Yes, its telling me there are 0 windows, but I added a window object in another class, check my post I'll edit it with the code.

Comment: Have you initialised windows? so something like app.windows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]. And also check that the window object you're passing into it is not nil? Maybe you're forgetting 'return self' in init method of yours?

Comment: I've returned self in the init method in the App class. Also in the App class I did self.windows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: And did you check if your window variable is nil right before addObject.

Comment: Paste both your header and source files

Comment: XMLParser.m: http://pastebin.com/Bz01Lkyy
Window.h: http://pastebin.com/Y16QfT4k
Window.m: http://pastebin.com/CYhgnDSG
App.h & App.m: http://pastebin.com/PqZiZMCa
There is something wrong in the XMLParser.m class, as you can see I've put some NSLogs there, and the ones after "test0" don't get printed out...If I put them all in comment and use your code as above, its telling me "there are 1 windows" and there need to be more windows in it (5 to be exact)

Comment: I see now, I think you're using 'continue' with the wrong idea. continue stops your current iteration and moves on to the next iteration, hence when any of those if statements fail, you never reach the bottom of the iteration (where you do addObject). Remove else { continue } statements and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are accessing the same variable. That is the gist of all the other comments and answers you are getting. It needs to be setup something like this. Keep in mind, your app may not be setup exactly like this. This is just a general structure to follow:

```
//myViewController.h
#import "WindowClass.h"
#import "AppClass.h"
@property (strong, nonatomic) AppClass *app;


//myViewController.m
#import "myViewController.h"
@synthesize app;

(id)init....{
   //...init code here
   //Synthesized objects must be initialized before they are accessed!
   self.app = [[AppClass alloc] init];
   return self;
}
(void)loadApp {
   WindowClass *aWindow = [[WindowClass alloc] init];
   [self.app.windowArray addObject:aWindow];
   return;
}
(void)loopFunction {
   for (WindowClass *window in self.app.windowArray) {
      NSLog(@"test.");
   }
   return;
}

//AppClass.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *windowArray;

//AppClass.m
#import "AppClass.h"
@synthesize windowArray;
```